# Refresh / Update WPF controls like win forms

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, invalidation

changing the text of a label (or sophisticatedly we can say a text-based progress bar). 
in winforms you just Invalidate / Update.

But how to do this in WPF without using Background Threads. ???

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
    public static class ExtensionMethods
{

   private static Action EmptyDelegate = delegate() { };
 

   public static void Refresh(this UIElement uiElement)
   {
      uiElement.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Render, EmptyDelegate);
   }
}

private void LoopingMethod()
{
   for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
   {
      label1.Content = i.ToString();
      label1.Refresh();
      Thread.Sleep(500);
   }
}
```

Reference: [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20201130173223/http://geekswithblogs.net/NewThingsILearned/archive/2008/08/25/refresh--update-wpf-controls.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps you should read more on the subject of [Bindings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163299.aspx)..

Basicly, bindings will manage this for you..

Comment: I guess it is not what OP is asking about. Refresh/Update is handy if you process data in main thread, but want to display progress in the UI. Refresh/Update forces the window to redraw itself, such that user will see the progress change. Bindings won't help in this case.