# In C#, how do you send a refresh/repaint message to a WPF grid or canvas?

Tags: c#, wpf, grid, repaint

How do you send a refresh message to a WPF grid or canvas?

In other words, I have noticed while in debug mode, I can write code that sends a line to the display and then, if that line is not right, I can adjust it -- but the previous line is still there.
Now, the code I am writing sends information to the display based on what the user clicks.  So this must mean that the display is not refreshed each time a new set of lines and boxes and text goes to the grid or canvas in WPF.

Using C# code, how do you send a refresh/repaint message to a WPF grid or canvas?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[Refresh update WPF Controls like Winforms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1831373/refresh-update-wpf-controls-like-win-forms)

```
public static class ExtensionMethods
{
   private static Action EmptyDelegate = delegate() { };

   public static void Refresh(this UIElement uiElement)
   {
      uiElement.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Render, EmptyDelegate);
   }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I'm used to winforms so this is only a guess, but look for an `Invalidate()` method.

Comment: I found InvalidateVisual() method for controls. The description popup says, "Invalidates the rendering of the element, and forces a complete new layout pass." And that appears to be the simple solution I sought." I think "Look for invalidate" is a good guess-suggestion.