# Not all charts are shown in my WPF app, but adding message boxes fixes things

Tags: c#, wpf

In my WPF application, I have one loop in which data is extracted from text files. On that basis, a data chart is shown and then a screenshot is taken.

Pseudo-code:

```
Loop Start
    data = extractdata();    
     if some condition in data           
        showchart();
        takescreenshot();
     end if
Loop End
```

When I run my actual code, not all charts are shown. The screen remains blank - only last of them appear on screen.

But when I add a message box to my code, everything works perfectly as show in below   pseudocode:

```
Loop Start
     data = extractdata();   
       if some condition in data        
          showchart();
          MessageBox.Show("Hello") // Addition of this line solves all problem           
          takescreenshot();
       end if
   Loop End
```

Both `showchart()` and `takescreenshot()` call other functions in different classes.

The inclusion of the line above is just a temporary solution which indicates my background code is working fine. My guess: the problem is something else, like focus of the WPF window or maybe some thing else.

What can I do? I can not post source code because that is very lengthy and divided into many files.

Comment: Try to refresh the picture see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2886532/in-c-how-do-you-send-a-refresh-repaint-message-to-a-wpf-grid-or-canvas

Comment: Do you show one single chart, sequentially updated or multiple charts, side by side? I suspect that your chart is overwritten before you see it.

Comment: Actually this application is not for showing chart but for taking screen shots of charts sequentially one by one at a time. And these screenshot are saved as jpg format which will have some use in other part of application

Comment: Some code is needed to help you here. Please provide some of the showchart (the part is showing a window) and the screenshot code (the error could be there, too). Why do you not create an image and save  that to a file?

Comment: If problem in background code of showchart() and screenshot() then they could not get solved by a messagebox, problem is something else and these codes are working perfectly in my other part of application and my screenshot function is doing same what you suggested it is creating an image of wpf window and saving that to a file , but as i know to create an image we have to draw that thing on screen

Comment: Can i close MessageBox by some code ?

Comment: Anyhow I found solution of my problem from http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/a05d5ce6-ef15-4a0c-91fb-727fa296dfa8 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2886532/in-c-how-do-you-send-a-refresh-repaint-message-to-a-wpf-grid-or-canvas?lq=1 thanks to **Alexm**

Answer (score 0):

Lets suppose your `showchart` already has a `Image` that is somehow 
brought to the screen in a `ContentControl` or `Image`.

You can just save it to a file by using the `System.Drawing.Save`
method.

[MSDN on System.Drawing Save](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ktx83wah.aspx)

You can even provide an ImageFormat and more detailed codec information.

Comment: Can i close MessageBox by some code ?